# Vector3d and sse2

Tags: computational-geometry, sse

I have a project, that have lots of operations on vector3d (3 double values).
 Is it possible to use sse2 to improve performance of vector operations (sum, dot product etc.) (for example use one m128 for x y and one for z w) and how?

Will it be better if someone has already tried it?

Comment: Yes, but for SIMD it's *much* better if you store an array of X, and array of Y, and an array of Z.  XYZ vectors don't map well to SIMD vectors because it costs a lot of shuffling to do a single dot product, vs. doing 4 dot-products at once with pure vertical operations.   These slides https://deplinenoise.wordpress.com/2015/03/06/slides-simd-at-insomniac-games-gdc-2015/ address that point well (linked from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks a lot. As far as I understand, you mean that I should multiply all elements in array x, then in array y and in array z, then sum the results. By it seems, that I misunderstand something.

Comment: If you are using Eigen, you may try the [`AlignedVector3` class](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/classEigen_1_1AlignedVector3.html) -- whether this actually helps, depends a lot on what you are doing. @PeterCordes suggestion was instead of storing lots of 3d vectors individually, to store one array of `x`, `y` and `z` values each (read the slides he linked to). This helps if you are doing the same operation on many different 3d-vectors simultaneously.

Comment: You're actually asking about vectorization, which might be performed automatically by compilers these days. Please see this old review: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/introduction-gcc-compiler-intrinsics-vector-processing